# How to implement the ADLivelyTableView class in a project that uses ARC

Tags: uitableview, core-animation, automatic-ref-counting

I have gone through the  ADLivelyTableView demo project but have not been able to import the ADLivelyTableView h and m files into my project successfully. It appears that the main issue is to do with ARC. I have experimented by converting the demo project into arc, specifically but converting just the LDMasterView.m file, and this simply removes all references to releasing objects, and so after this conversion, the use ARC option under build settings is now ON and the app works. So i figured that the ADLivelyTableView .m and .h files dont need converting, but when these are imported into my project, i get all sorts of ARC errors for these two blocks of code:

```
 if (block != _transformBlock) {
        Block_release(_transformBlock);
        _transformBlock = Block_copy(block);
    }
}
```

and

```
@implementation ADLivelyTableView

- (void)dealloc {
    Block_release(_transformBlock);
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I dont get why these errors didnt show when turning on ARC in the demo project. id prefer finding a solution rather than trying to import my entire application to the demo project instead! The errors are as follows:

```
ARC Casting Rules: Cast of block pointer type 'ADLivelyTransform (aka NSTimeINterval (^)CALayer*_strong, float) to C pointer type 'const void *' required a bridged cast.
ARC Casting Rules: Cast of C Pointer ....(Same as above)
```

Also, once this issue is resolved, it is supposed to be as simple as just importing the ADLivelyTableView .h and .m files and then adding the line :

```
ADLivelyTableView * livelyTableView = (ADLivelyTableView *)self.tableView;
    livelyTableView.initialCellTransformBlock = ADLivelyTransformFan;
```

into my viewDidLoad section? or is that bit supposed to be edited for my specific table?

Thanks for your help,
Regards,
Rami

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the Compiler Flags for ADLivelyTableView.m.

Kindly try to add -fno-objc-arc.

Comment: I've added compiler flag but I am getting error again. log is 2015-01-23 18:25:23.494 myProject[13905:70b] -[UITableView setInitialCellTransformBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a228c00
2015-01-23 18:25:23.498 myProject[13905:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView setInitialCellTransformBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a228c00'